# Error in my sql order by query

Tags: php, mysql

### Here is my query that i want to run in a page to find recent project in a category

```
"SELECT * FROM project where cat_id=".$category."order by id desc limit 1";
```

and my project table has following column
id
cat_id
title 
year client
description

when i am executing this query in localhost phpMyAdmin panel it runs successfully; but when i am using it on my project its getting following error

Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'by id desc limit 1' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to have a space before the `ORDER`

```
"SELECT * FROM project WHERE cat_id=".$category." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 2):

try this
make a space before `order` clause

```
"SELECT * FROM project where cat_id=".$category." order by id desc limit 1";
```

Comment: We made the same response at the same time. Good timing.